# Switching Portfolio back to the new version

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

My portfolio in SFMC was switched to Classic content but I'd like to go back to the most recent version.  I can't seem to find a way to do this.  Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

Switching back to the content uploaded as part of the newer Content Builder can be accessed through the Content Builder link in Email Studio.

[image]

---

If you are referring to upgrading the portfolio within Classic Content, this to be done through support. I did this recently and they were a bit confused by what I meant, so pro-tip: Ask to activate the business rule **Enhanced Portfolio Access**.